# How to address new information (compared to the submitted application) during an interview?

Tags: application, faculty-application, interview

My question has some similarities to [Should I omit some of my qualifications in my application materials to “surprise” with during an interview?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36824/should-i-omit-some-of-my-qualifications-in-my-application-materials-to-surprise). However, in my case, the additional "surprising" information came after the application was submitted, so there was no chance for me to include it from the beginning.

Let's say (for a teaching-heavy job) that I received an amazing teaching evaluation after submitting my application, or I came up with a teaching plan that addresses the department's recently updated course curriculum.

I guess that I can in any case *mention* this information, but I thought about giving it a bit more focus, since that information might be really useful for landing the job. Therefore I wonder: Would it be appropriate to prepare some materials that I would show live during the interview?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could prepare a couple of different scenarios and adopt the "news only" version or the one giving more details depending on the the *live reaction* of the committee.
It depends on time constrain, too.

Likely, if the news is indeed surprising, you can use the "in depth" material (physically as support or just being mentally prepared) for the question part that normally follows the candidate's presentation.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any more tips about gauging the live reaction? Do you have something in mind like "mention the news-only version and wait if anyone asks further questions about it"? (In my situation, there is relatively much time, and the interview is on a different day than the presentation.)

Comment: @lighthousekeeper ok that split totally changes the situation. By gauging live reaction I even mean feeling the audience "emotional" response. You are speaking to them, so for some of us it is a relatively easy judgement. Perhaps you can propose a further explanation. Without time constraints, even the presentation might be a dialogue. Or you can make it so in spite of the formal environment.

Comment: Not really totally.... Follow your feelings as above. Most likely in the interview you'll be expected to say more. But put the seeds at least without giving the impression that you are supposed to arrive there and adjust things.

Answer (score 1):

I worry that if you withhold important aspects of your qualifications to "wow" them later you might not even reach the point of an interview in which you could make it happen.

Competition for jobs now is very tough. You have to make the initial cut in order to reach any consideration at all. Then, probably a second cut in which you are discussed along with other candidates in order to determine who will be invited for interviews. If you miss either of those, you are sunk.

I'd suggest including all important qualifications. Perhaps they will come up in an interview and you can, then, stress some things, but you gotta get there first.

But if something new comes up along the way that makes you more qualified, don't neglect to mention, or even stress, it.

And, if the new material would materially affect your chances of reaching the interview stage, then you might consider asking if you could provide a supplement to the application when it first arises. A department head might be the person to ask, or the hiring committee's chair if available.

And there is no reason not to be prepared for either questions or whatever comes up. "Is there anything more we should know?" "Well yes, yes there is...".

Comment: I don't how the first three paragraphs refer to the OP's situation. The question of withholding important information to wow them later was asked in the linked question. This question only asks what to do when such a information becomes available after the application has been submitted.

Comment: Indeed, the last paragraph is the one most relevant to my situation. I wonder if you can expand more on it.